# FIFA Club World Cup

Tags: football, tournaments, fifa

I'm confused about the [FIFA Club World Cup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Club_World_Cup).

Does the FIFA Club World Cup have any relation whatsoever to the actual World Cup, or is it a completely unrelated competition?  (e.g. does the outcome of the FIFA Club Worldcup have any effect on the World Cup?)

Answer (score 10):

FIFA Club World Cup is **NOT** the actual World Cup. The two tournaments are not related whatsoever.

### FIFA World Cup

This is a competition organized by FIFA (Federation Internationale de Football Association). This tournament is played `once every four years`. This is contested by the 209 member **`countries`**. These 209 countries compete in the qualifiers of each region and 31 teams qualify (The 32nd spot is reserved for the hosting nation) for the actual World Cup. The current champions are Spain who defeated Netherlands 1-0  in the finals in  Johannesburg, South Africa on 11th July 2010. The next World Cup is scheduled to be played in Brazil in 2014.

### FIFA Club World Cup

This is a competition organized by FIFA that is played `every year`. This is contested between the top **`clubs`** of each continent. Totally 7 teams contest (Champions League winners of the 6 continents along with the current champion of the host nation) for this trophy. The current champions are Corinthians who defeated Chelsea 1–0 in Yokohama, Japan on 16th December 2012. The next Club World Cup is scheduled to take place in Morocco in December 2013.

Answer (score 3):

FIFA Club World Cup is the competition that organized by FIFA annually, at first, it has been host by Brazil in 2000 in the first edition. Six continental winners, host, and the latest Intercontinental Cup winner has been invited.

Before that, the main competition is the Intercontinental Cup, the match(es - until 1979) between the European winners versus the South American winners. The last edition of the IC is 2004 as the European winners in that year, FC Porto, won the match.

For the revised edition as the new CWC, after the absorption by FIFA, all of the continental winners (total six) will be invited. The European winners and the South American winners will be automatically seeded to the semifinals, leaving the rest to play for the place in their rounds.

At first two revised editions (2005 and 2006), only the continental winners have been invited. The host nation highest league winners has been invited to the tournament since 2007 edition and so on.

For the further tournament details, maybe [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFA_Club_World_Cup) can help you.

For the question about relation, the answer is no. Except that both tournaments have been organized by FIFA, and the winner of the tournament gets the special titleholder badge to be shown on their jersey until the new winners has been decided.